# What is the Hadith about missing the Takbeer E Oola of salah (takbir at the beginning of the prayer)?

Tags: salat, hadith, source-identification, takbir

What is the Hadith about missing the Takbeer E Oola os Salah?

Mention your answer with reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse me but sometimes it would be helpful if you added some explanation, as for me I have never heard this indication "*Takbeer E oola*" before, i only know it as "takbeer or takbeerat (as it is only one) al-Ihram" or takbir al-Iftitah or opening takbir) or just the Takbeer to begin a prayer!

In many hadith collections you could find the following hadith:

> Narrated Ali ibn AbuTalib: The key to prayer is purification; its
>   beginning is takbir and its end is taslim.
>
> [Sunan [abi-Dawud](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/228), [ibn Majah](http://sunnah.com/urn/1302880) in one version on the authority of abu Sa'id al-Khudry and also in Jami' [at-Tirmdihi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/90)]

Which shows that you only enter/start/join a prayer with a Takbeer! As with saying Allahu Akbar you enter the prayer and keep away of anything else... this is the right explanation for the Expression "tahrimuha تَحْرِيمُهَا" in Arabic. And with as salamu alaykum you leave the prayer and are allowed ("tahliluha تَحْلِيلُهَا") to anything else!

There's also a Hadith

> "قال صلى الله عليه وسلم : ( إنه لا تتم صلاة لأحد من الناس حتى يتوضأ ، فيضع الوضوء مواضعه ، ثم يقول: الله أكبر )"

in the Book of Imam at-Tabarani, which says something like:

> No prayer is complete unless you make the purification (the right way) and afterwards say. Allahu Akbar" (this is my own interpretation take it with care, a similar haidth can be found in sunan [abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/467))

Now the Madhabs have a slight difference in the definition or technical terms some regard it as farz/fard/rukn/shart (obligatory). But all of them are in consensus when it comes to takbeerat al-Ihram (the takbir to begin a prayer) and say a prayer without it is void.

Now what happens if somebody missed it you can find the following fatwa or Narration from how it was/should be handled from [Muwatta'](http://sunnah.com/malik/3/23) al Imam Malik:

> Yahya related to me from Malik that Ibn Shihab used to say, "When a
>   man catches the raka he says, 'Allah is greater' once, and that takbir
>   is enough for him."
>
> Malik added, "That is if he intended to begin the prayer by that
>   takbir "
>
> Malik was asked about a man who began with the imam but forgot the
>   opening takbir and the takbir of the ruku until he had done one raka.
>   Then he remembered that he had not said the takbir at the opening nor
>   in the ruku,so he said the takbir in the second raka. He said, "I
>   prefer that he start his prayer again, but if he forgets the opening
>   takbir with the imam and says the takbir in the first ruku, I consider
>   that enough for him if he intends by it the opening takbir."
>
> Malik said, about some one who prayed by himself and forgot the
>   opening takbir, "He begins his prayer afresh ."
>
> Malik said, about an imam who forgot the opening takbir until he had
>   finished his prayer, "I think that he should do the prayer again, and
>   those behind him, even if they have said the takbir."

See also [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/69853). And this [fatwa](http://www.sistani.org/arabic/qa/0370/page/2/#4312) of the shia'a marji' a-Sistani in Arabic saying the prayer without a takbeer to begin the prayer is void!

And Allah knows best!